# PhpUnit : Error: Unable to access jarfile ./../src/Java/File.jar

Tags: symfony, phpunit

When I run the test of my page, I encounter this error message that I do not have on the browser:

Error: Unable to access jarfile ./../src/Java/File.jar

Here is the call to the file in my controller (symfony 4):

```
 exec("java -jar ./../src/Java/File.jar $params",$tab);
```

Here is my test method :

```
public function testView(){

        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET','/test/1');

        if( Response::HTTP_OK !== $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()){
           echo $crawler->filter('div.exception-message-wrapper')->text();  
           echo $crawler->filter('.trace-html-1')->text();
        }

        static::assertEquals(
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
        );
    }
```

thanks for your help

Comment: If you would allow me to guess, I'd guess it's because the file is not at the given location because the relative reference does hide it's actual location. Using an absolute path  might help as well as using the same working directory under test as under those non-test circumstances you report as wokring.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you could try using a path to the jar which will be relative to the `__DIR__`.

```
 exec("java -jar " . __DIR__ . "../src/Java/File.jar $params", $tab);
```

To understand, you can read more about `__DIR__` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: when you run the `exec` command it assumes a run path relative to the path from which the initial php file was loaded from. For example index.php. That is probably non the same path that your test is running from. Best bet here is to use the absolute path in your exec command with `__DIR__`